# code with incorrect result for big N. Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, precision, floating-accuracy

The below code gives wrong answer. It should give approximately 0.5 which is the average of an array with many random numbers between 0 an 1. I think the problem is because N is "to big", or perhaps the precision on the generated random number?. The code works well for smaller values of N (10^7, 10^6, etc). Some advices will be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

```
(defun randvec(n)
    (let ((arr (make-array n)))
        (dotimes (i n)
            (setf (aref arr i) (random 1.0))
        )
        arr
    )
)

(defparameter N (expt 10 8))
(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))
(defparameter vector1 (randvec N))
(format t "~a~%" (/ (reduce #'+ vector1) (length vector1)))
```

Comment: Apologies by typo errors  I mean 0 and 1; "too big"

Comment: You're running into a classic example of precision failure in numerical analysis - adding numbers of different scale.  Divide each number /before/ adding, instead - then you'll be adding numbers of the same scale.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Precision of floating point numbers**

You are computing with single precision floating point numbers. By adding up all random numbers you get a single-float number. The more numbers you add, the larger the float will be. This eventually causes your result to have not enough precision.

double-floats like `1.0d0` have a higher precision than single-floats like `1.0s0`. By default `1.0` is read as a single-float. `(RANDOM 1.0d0)` will compute a double float.

```
(defun randvec (n)
  (let ((v (make-array n)))
    (dotimes (i n v)
      (setf (aref v i) (random 1.0d0)))))   ; create a double float random number

(defun test (&optional (n 10))
  (setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))  
  (let ((v (randvec n)))
    (/ (reduce #'+ v) (length v))))
```

Example:

```
CL-USER 58 > (test (expt 10 8))
0.4999874882753848D0
```

**Style**

Please use common Lisp programming style when programming in Common Lisp:

- don't use global variables, if not necessary. Write functions with local variables instead.
- if you define a global variable with `defparameter`, don't name it `n`, but `*n*`.
- format and indent your code correctly. Indentation should be done with editor help.
- don't use parentheses on their own line.

See my example above.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, thank you for the advice on lisp programming style.
Regarding to the use of parenthesis on their own line, I use it because 
it give me clarity, also I have seen some books on lisp that use it 
(the art of lisp programming of Robin Jones Clive Maynard Ian Stewart, 
for example). Although is a little old.

Comment: @Francisco: don't use dangling parentheses. Learn to use an editor which indents code and shows corresponding parentheses. The code will be much more compact and readable. Your eye and your brain would not be able to see which parentheses are aligned anyway, when there is some distance between them. The editor can easily show it.